# What "row reduction clauses" does Oracle support? (for Excel Power Query)

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, powerquery, top-n

I want to add an Oracle table as a data source in Excel 2016 **Power Query** (via ODBC):

[image]

---

At the bottom of the ODBC dialog, there is an option to specify the *"Supported row reduction clauses (optional)"*:

[image]

---

**Question:**

What option applies to Oracle 18c?

1. (None)
2. TOP
3. LIMIT and OFFSET
4. LIMIT
5. ANSI SQL-compatible

Comment: Why not try it and see for yourself? Worst that could happen is that you'd generate some invalid SQL, and then you'd know...

Comment: Oracle is ANSI compatible in this regard (supporting the standard SQL `FETCH` clause). `TOP` and `LIMIT` are proprietary functions that some other DBMS use.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports

```
OFFSET n ROWS
```

and

```
FETCH FIRST|NEXT n ROWS ONLY
or
FETCH FIRST|NEXT n ROWS WITH TIES
```

[Docs here - see "row_limiting_clause"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)